# How to add Maven project to IDEA?

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

I want to ask how to make IDEA looks like on first screenshot where you have just "Maven", "Spring", etc. Not like my IDEA with "Maven Archetype" or "Spring Initializr".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRyP6.jpg

Comment: on your second screenshot, you can select maven within the "new project" window. This could be due to updates on this window. Is this not enough?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.